# make listing through phonegap

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am making an application in which there will show me a list in which it contain all the contact , but I want to make it in phone gap. any idea about this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
Its on phonegap's documentation page on how to read a phones contacts database.

[Phonegap Contacts](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: @scrienym, thanks for the reply, yes, but how can I show those list in  a table view ?? any idea

Comment: I think what you're looking for in that case is the fact that navigator.contacts is an array of contacts objects, using this array you should iterate through it and for each element create a jquery mobile list element containing the information you wish to show see here for all the lists available [Jquery-mobile lists](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks buddy I have another problem is that I get all the contact but how can I get his id   /* get all contacts from device */
function getContacts(){
 var optFilter = new ContactFindOptions();
 optFilter.filter = "";  // to return all contacts
 optFilter.multiple = true; // return multiple results
 fields = ["name"];
 
 // get all contacts
 navigator.contacts.find(fields, gcsSuccess, gcsError, optFilter);
}